# dynamic pivoting

Tags: oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am hoping to get some help on a view which needs to be pivoted, I am not sure though.
    View is in following format:

```
CASE       CASE_ORDER     MANAGER    MONTHLY_CASES      FISCAL_CASES                                                                
case_1          1           John            15             84          
case_1          1           Jeff            10             80  
case_2          2           John            20             90  
case_2          2           Jeff            13             65  
case_3          3           John            7              72  
case_3          3           Jeff            17             70
```

My final chart should look like the following:

```
CASE  CASE_ORDER   JOHN_CURR_MONTH  JOHN_FY        JOHN_CURR_MONTH  JOHN_FY               
case_1     1            15                84            10            80  
case_2     2            20                90            13            65  
case_3     3             7                72            17            70
```

My problem is that managers can change and so does the number of managers from month to month, 
so I can't hard code their names (ie. 'mgr1' and 'mgr2') and use DECODE. It has to be dynamic...

Comment: There are some very good hits if you simply google for "oracle pivot dynamic". Did you try anything?

Comment: I certainly looked around before posting my message. As I said in my original post my current working code uses the hard-coded names for manages but it can change from time to time, so I want to make it dynamic which I haven't figured out yet. Can you suggest some solution.

Comment: Thing is, you you google for exactly "oracle dynamic pivot", you'll find an asktom article that describes an option for dynamic pivot. Did you try it? Is it not an option?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your suggestion, I figured it out. In fact there is a similar answer in tom kyte's blog (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42asktom-1653097.html) which I modified for my purpose. Here it is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dynamic_pivot_proc ( p_cursor IN OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )  
AS  
l_query LONG := 'SELECT case_order, case';   
BEGIN  
FOR x IN (SELECT DISTINCT manager FROM test_table ORDER BY 1 )  
LOOP  
    l_query := l_query ||  
    REPLACE( q'|, MAX(DECODE(manager,'$X$',monthly_total)) $X$_current_month|',   
            '$X$', dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(x.manager) ) ||  
    REPLACE( q'|, MAX(DECODE(manager,'$X$',fiscal_total)) $X$_fy|',   
           '$X$', dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(x.manager) );  
END LOOP;  
l_query := l_query || ' FROM test_table 
                        GROUP BY case_order, case
                        ORDER BY case_order ';
OPEN p_cursor FOR l_query;
END;

SQL> variable x refcursor;  
SQL> exec dynamic_pivot_proc( :x );  
SQL> print x
```

### CASE    CASE_ORDER    JEFF_CURRENT_MONTH     JEFF_FY     JOHN_CURRENT_MONTH       JOHN_FY

1           case_1                10                                80                  15                                         84
2           case_2                13                                65                  20                                     90
3           case_3                17                                70                   7                                      72

Now the thing is instead of printing the result I want to store it in a view. How do I achieve that? I tried to modify the line
l_query LONG := 'SELECT case_order, case';
with
l_query LONG := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SELECT case_order, case';
Needless to say that it did not work because CREATE OR REPLACE is a DDL statement, so some how I have to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.